# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths animation covers upper cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I try use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` with animation `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` the cell that I am deleting covers the above cell (in animation) and then disappears. I made a small example, where each cell background is in different colour.

Before I delete cell table view looks like this:

[image]

When animation is happening, the selected cell (gray colour) slides up on top of the cell above and then disappears.

[image]

The end results is correct:

[image]

How can I make the selected cell to slide underneath the cell that is above it and not on top? The code is very simple:

TableViewController.h:

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

TableViewController.m:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"


@implementation TableViewController{
    int cellCount;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cellCount=100;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cellCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor =[self getRandomColor];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cellCount--;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

-(UIColor *)getRandomColor
{
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed by adding this:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.layer.zPosition = -1;`

This ensures that the layer being animated 'away' is below any other layer in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Tne solution is to bring deleted cells in the back, by setting their zPosition like that

```
[indexPaths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *removedIndexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   UITableViewCell *removedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:removedIndexPath];
   removedCell.layer.zPosition = -1;
}];
```

You also need to put back the zPosition to 0 on reused cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   ...
   cell.layer.zPosition = 0;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and it is very annoying. I figured what is causing it - selection of the cell. This only works wrong on the selected cell, so if you for example remove a cell one below the selection, it will animate just fine.

I came up with temporary solution which is not perfect, but does animate deletion of selected row correctly. Instead of writing your code in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, use **shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath**:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    return NO;
}
```

The downside of this solution is that you don't get selection effect. I also tried sending back the selected cell with sendSubviewToBack, but that didn't change anything. Another downside is that row is deleted even if user misclicks and wanted to cancel the action.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: temporally adding tableViewFootView likes following:

```
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        self.tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
        //remove data
        [self.infoArray removeObjectAtIndex:ip.row];

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
            [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];

        }];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [CATransaction commit];
```